# Как обновить определённые данные в JSON?

Tags: python, json

Есть **JSON** файл. В которым следующие данные:

```
{"_TIMES": "1", "RunestoneRare": 0, "EssenceRare": 0, "DustRare": 0, "RunestoneEpic": 0, "EssenceEpic": 0, "DustEpic": 0, "RunestoneLegendary": 0, "EssenceLegendary": 0, "DustLegendary": 0, "Ruby": 0}
```

Есть код, в котором я проверяю значение `REWARDS` на совпадение слова из **JSON** и хочу прибавлять +1 к значению:

```
import json

REWARD = 'RunestoneRare'
i = 0

REWARDS = {
    "_TIMES":"1", 
    "RunestoneRare":0, 
    "EssenceRare":0, 
    "DustRare":0, 
    "RunestoneEpic":0, 
    "EssenceEpic":0, 
    "DustEpic":0, 
    "RunestoneLegendary":0, 
    "EssenceLegendary":0, 
    "DustLegendary":0, 
    "Ruby": 0
}

to_json = REWARDS

with open('sw_templates.json', 'w') as f:
    f.write(json.dumps(to_json))

with open('sw_templates.json', 'r') as f:
    if REWARD == 'RunestoneRare':
        json_data = json.load(f)
        print(json_data['RunestoneRare'])
        json_data['RunestoneRare'] = i + 1

with open('sw_templates.json', 'w') as f:
    f.write(json.dumps(json_data))
```

---

При первом выполнение кода, в `RunestoneRare` появляется значение 1, как бы уже радует, но при втором выполнение, всё то же значение.

Пробовал: `++i`, `json_data['RunestoneRare'] += 1`, `json_data['RunestoneRare'] = i + 1` - Не помогает.

Comment: json_data['RunestoneRare'] = json_data['RunestoneRare'] + 1 еще не пробовали

Comment: @Jack_oS. Помогает, но ошибку я свою нашёл.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка заключается в том, что при запуске кода, создаю всё по новой.

```
with open('sw_templates.json', 'w') as f:
        f.write(json.dumps(to_json))
```

Убрал из кода и всё работает.